# Import react components with absolute path

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, enzyme

Here is my test file

```
// /imports/components/main.test.js
import React from 'react'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import Main from './main'
import TextInput from "/imports/ui/textInput"
...
```

and the main.js has

```
// /imports/components/main.js
import { action1 } from "/imports/actions/myAction"
```

but it throws an error when I run the test, saying

`Cannot find module '/imports/actions/myAction' from 'main.js'`

If I comment the `import './main'`, same thing happen with importing TextInput. I have no issue with importing modules in node_modules.

How can I tell Jest or webpack to import the component using absolute path from project directory (i.e `import Foo from /imports/...`)?

Comment: If there is a directory called imports at the same level of your test file, you should at a dot like: **import TextInput from "./imports/ui/textInput"**

Comment: Sorry I missed the directory structure. I added the location path for the components and test file which is basically inside /imports as well.

Comment: you can simply import like `import TextInput from "../ui/textInput" ` in main.test.js and `import { action1 } from "../actions/myAction" `. If you want to import with absolute path, then you must do aliasing in your webpack.config and then import like `import { action1 } from "imports/actions/myAction" `.

Comment: The `../actions/myAction` is imported from main.js, not test file, and it is working perfectly fine on the component. And I don't need to import that on test file. In test file, I just need to import the main.js component and textInput for testing shallow rendering. I am sorry if it is confusing.

Comment: https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver works for me

Comment: @zeraien yup works for me too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My file structure follows exactly the same pattern as yours. To teach Jest into using imports beginning with a `/`, I use [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) and its handy `root` option. My `.babelrc` for Jest looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "meteor"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-react-constant-elements",
    "transform-react-inline-elements",
    "transform-react-remove-prop-types",
      ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["../"],
      "alias": {
        "react-router-dom": "react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js",
        "redux": "redux/dist/redux.min.js",
        "react-redux": "react-redux/dist/react-redux.min.js"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

As I'm using Meteor which customized its root imports, I hide my Jest usage and configuration into a `.jest` directory at the root of my repository allowing me to have a specific `.babelrc` without risking conflicts with Meteor's one.

Comment: Hey this looks promising. I'll have a go after couple days and give updates here. Thanks for the inputs!

Comment: Sorry for the late update, but this solution works great! Installed the resolver module and set the root, now I able to use `import .. from '/imports/foo`. Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

Better way to solve relative path import issue, is by creating `jsconfig.json` file adjacent to `package.json` file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

then `import { action1 } from "actions/myAction";` will work

Comment: `"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from"]` just added this plugin in package.json#babel. Hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: @Daniels solution worked fine, without having to add yet another plugin for something as trivial as this

Comment: `baseUrl` should be `.` and not the word "imports" as stated

Comment: @vsync Thanks for the feedback, It was a typo from my side. It should be directory from which you would like to set baseUrl. In my case, it is "src"

Comment: You might need to restart such as `npm start`

Answer (score 30):

If you're using Create React App, you can set up the absolute imports path in a `jsconfig.json` (need to create in a fresh JavaScript template) or `tsconfig.json` (already created in the TypeScript template) at the root of your project to serve your usage.

Example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Official docs: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to create an `.env` file within the root directory of your project.

Within it you will add `NODE_PATH=src/`

Thats all

Save the file and restart your dev environment in terminal.

Afterwards, you will go through your project and update some import statements accordingly.

Comment: This is now depricated in preference of using a jsconfig.json file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437517/how-to-add-jsconfig-json-to-existing-vscode-project-w-o-breaking-it

Answer (score 2):

With webpack(v4) and babel, you can provide absolute paths in your directory.
Follow these steps
In your .babelrc file, make this entry for plugins.Make sure you have babel-plugin-root-import in your package.json as well.

```
"plugins": [
    [
        "babel-plugin-root-import",
        {
          "paths": [
            {
              "rootPathPrefix": "~",
              "rootPathSuffix": "./"
            },
            {
              "rootPathPrefix": "@src",
              "rootPathSuffix": "src"
            },
            {
                "rootPathPrefix": "@any-other-folder",
                "rootPathSuffix": "src/client/../any-other-folder"
              }
          ]
        }
      ]
]
```

Now if you run into eslint issue, you can add these lines in your eslintrc:

```
"settings": {
"import/resolver": {
  "babel-plugin-root-import": [
    {
      "rootPathPrefix": "@src",
      "rootPathSuffix": "src"
    },
    {
      "rootPathPrefix": "@any-other-folder",
      "rootPathSuffix": "src/client/../any-other-folder"
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

Now to make your editor recognize these paths, you can create this entry in jsconfig file.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["/*"],
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
      "@any-other-folder/*": ["src/client/../any-other-folder/*"] ==> absolute path to any other folder
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had jest configs in **package.json** file (under "jest" key). So I just have added there this row:

```
"modulePaths": ["<rootDir>/src/"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below in your jsconfig.json/tsconfig.json file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

suppose folder structure is like **src->components->Header.tsx** then you arevable to import as below.

> import Header from 'components/Header';

because baseUrl mentioned in tsconfig.json/jsconfig.json as **src**.

> Note: nothing else is required but if you want to import with prefix @/ way then please let me know.