# How to import component correctly?

Tags: reactjs

This is maybe stupid question, but I am new and this problem took me a couple of hours :/. I am trying to import component like this:

```
import * as test from "../../../../common/containers/sidebar/Sidebar";
```

and file where I write this line is located in :

```
 src/pages/example/containers/example.
```

above path of 'Sidebar' is correct but react gives me 'Sidebar' is not defined.
I found some kind of similar questions but it didn't help me so please if anyone has anny suggestions write below, huge thanks! and one more thing is this correct way to import files like this - I mean '../../../../'  <- this looks like little weird for me.

Comment: you can import with relative or absolute paths so it is correct. maybe path is wrong.
Your path will work for [...path]/Sidebar.js and [...path]/Sidebar/index.js

Comment: For the `Sidebar` is not defined, do you mean `test.Sidebar`?
As for the long paths, you can try https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver

Comment: What does your file tree look like?

Comment: Did you `export`your component? Here more about `default` and `named` export https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import react components with absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993461/import-react-components-with-absolute-path)

Comment: thanks everyone, I am gonna try everything and let you know ^^ thanks.

Comment: in React you import a component like so > `import { Sidebar } from '../../../../common/containers/sidebar/Sidebar`. then to render `Sidebar` you will write `<Sidebar />` within the `render` `return` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `rootDir` option to your jest config. And then just import components as from the global path.

For example if root is your `src` folder. Just import `pages/example/containers/example`