# How to add jsconfig.json to existing vscode project w/o breaking it

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, visual-studio-code

I have React project, currently not using `jsconfig.json` file.
Recently I got the following warning message, when generating a build (yarn):

> Setting NODE_PATH to resolve modules absolutely has been deprecated in favor of setting baseUrl in jsconfig.json (or tsconfig.json if you are using TypeScript) and will be removed in a future major release of create-react-app.

I saw "local fixes" to add base_url [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5692) [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/6656), but I am afraid it will break my build in  other places.

What is the safest way to fix this issue in an existing project?
What additional settings are required in `jsconfig.json`?
Or should I not worry at all and ignore it?

Comment: What are you concerned will happen if you add a jsconfig? Do things not work if you just add one?

Comment: @MattBierner Major: Does adding jsconfig.json have side effects? Minor: How will it affect my package.json? Both can be tested But I prefer to have a better understading before I start...

Comment: @MattBierner Just noticed that it applies to *build* only, not dev version

Comment: A jsconfig just defines a JavaScript project for VS Code. See [here for more details](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson). Since it sounds like you are not using a jsconfig for building, you should try adding one and seeing if it causes any issues in the editor

Comment: @MattBierner Clearly I have to try. But I do not know how to define one... Since I did not need it (before) :-). The link you sent (which I saw before) does not clarify the interaction with React (jsx) etc... Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> Setting NODE_PATH to resolve modules absolutely has been deprecated in
>   favor of setting baseUrl in jsconfig.json (or tsconfig.json if you are
>   using TypeScript) and will be removed in a future major release of
>   create-react-app.

This is a warning stating that the method you use for the absolute path in your project i.e. adding `NODE_PATH` in your `.env` will be deprecated, in favor of setting baseUrl in either `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json`

To fix this, you can add `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` in your root directory and set the baseUrl as `src`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

Now remove `NODE_PATH` in your `.env`, this won't break anything in your current code and will remove the warning.

> Note: `paths` in `jsconfig` or `tsconfig` is still not supported in CRA 
>   if you are planning to use this feature in your CRA project you have to wait

Comment: Seems like CRA v3 support it now, I haven't tested yet. https://blog.logrocket.com/whats-new-in-create-react-app-3-950049f54f92/

Comment: FYI - I've added this jsconfig.json but the warning does not go away.

Comment: you have to also remove `NODE_PATH` from your `.env`

Comment: @saurabh adding `NODE_PATH=src/` did the trick in .env file but jsconfig.json didn't and the issue is we have .env file in .gitignore file so what to do any help to work with jsconfig.json in react project or do i have to use the same .env due to CRA doesn't support this feature yet as per your "Note:"