# Auto Import of React Components in Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm using JavaScript (not TypeScript) and using the latest Visual Studio Code.

I'm not able to get auto import of components working. I've been using the [Auto Import plugin by steoates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport), but it doesn't seem to work. I haven't seen any recent notes about this.

Are there other plugins I've not found that help with auto-import of React Components?

Comment: 2022: This extension seems to work fine with JS too: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuclleaR.vscode-extension-auto-import

Answer (score 139):

## Update 2018

VS Code now handles this natively via a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) and the [JavaScript Language Service](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio).

Create the file `jsconfig.json` at your project root and make sure to set `checkJs` to `true`:

Creating a JS Config file, allows Visual Studio to treat the folder as an **Explicit Project**.  Without it, JS files opened in VS Code are treated as independent units, and there is no common project context between any two files.

#### Example:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

#### Code Action / Quick Fix

Missing modules will show up with a [Code Action](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_code-action) (AKA "Quick Fix") with an option to import.  You can click on the lightbulb  or use <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`.`</kbd>

[image: code action > import]

#### Auto Imports / IntelliSense

[Auto Imports](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_auto-imports) will show you available components as you type and import them when selected

[image: intellisense > auto import]

#### Further Reading

- [Visual Studio Code Automatic Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015835/1366033)
- [How to add jsconfig.json to existing vscode project w/o breaking it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56437517/1366033)

Comment: My typescript components weren't autoimporting. From your example I noticed *baseUrl* wasn't present in my tsconfig. Adding that started populating the auto-import suggestions with my local modules. Thanks!

Comment: To check if a JavaScript file is part of JavaScript project, just open the file in VS Code and run the **JavaScript: Go to Project Configuration** command. This command opens the `jsconfig.json` that references the JavaScript file. -- [JavaScript in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_auto-imports)

Comment: Please update the answer for 2021.

Comment: @Tanvirgeek - is there new advice as of 2021 that needs to be included?

Comment: @KyleMit - "jsx": "react" is not working in 2021. I had to convert it to: "jsx": "react-jsx"

Comment: Congratulations !! very helpful your answer, thanks =)

Comment: It changes the path for component, to: 

import Login from "components/Login"; 

but it needs to be: 

import Login from "./components/Login";

how to fix that? @Tanvirgeek

Comment: I figured it out, inside the jsconfig.json it needs to be  "baseUrl": "./../src", and not as of  "baseUrl": "./src"

Answer (score 14):

Double check that the extension is enabled by navigating to Extensions > searching for "Auto Import".  You should see the following:

[image: enabled extension]

Comment: that is what my page looks like and says next to it "This extension is enabled globally" so I assume it is enabled.I'm expecting to see a suggestion to import here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwlhijfg1lecox9/autoimport.png?dl=0

Comment: The question explicitly states that they are not using TS, this extension however is exactly made for auto-importing TS and TSX files. Thanks for the recommendation though. It guided me towards this other extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuclleaR.vscode-extension-auto-import and it works fine (and with JS too).

Answer (score 3):

**I solved this issue by opening single project folder** /project/my-project in vscode....
Seems all the .js configs are auto-configured this way.

Before this, I had opened /projects folder with multiple projects inside, and the imports suggestion and other stuff was not working at all.

Comment: Thanks, I had opened my front and back at the same time, did you find how to get work this with two projects?

Comment: I did not try. My guess is you can use two separate vs windows, then open folders of each project respectively. If vscode "understands" the language of your projects (react in this case), it should auto import needed classes. Or at least suggest.