# What is the best way to manage your actions in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have heard it's good to keep them all in one folder in your src folder but then if I ever wanted to use the action from somewhere deep in my component tree, I'd have to:

```
import increment from '../../../../../actions/increment';
```

Alternatively each action could be kept in the folder I'm using it in, but then if two different components needed to use the action, I'd have to send the action through props or make a copy of it.

I'm sorry I'm a complete newbie with Redux. Is there a nice concise way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import react components with absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993461/import-react-components-with-absolute-path)

Comment: _"So I have heard it's good to keep them all in one folder in your src folder "_ - where did you read that? "good" according to whom?

Comment: Just in a Redux tutorial. Figured there could be a chance it's standard practice

Comment: @Trunks159 Please provide a link to the specific tutorial you saw that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow current standards, you don't even write action types or action creators. Please read [Why Redux Toolkit is How To Use Redux Today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today).

As for the question as hand, file organization is handled in the [Redux Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/)